# Simple REST API Call from logic app - Azure

Tags: rest, azure, azure-api-apps, azure-logic-apps

First of all I want you to know that I am new to Azure.
Recently, I am trying to work on Azure Logic App.
My motive is to make a simple REST API Call from the HTTP API (from Microsoft) and mail the response JSON via Office 365 connector.

Here is my code:

```
{  
        ..  
        .  
        .  
          "triggers": {  
              "http": {  
                "recurrence": {  
                    "frequency": "Day",  
                    "interval": 1  
                },  
                "type": "Http",  
                "inputs": {  
                    "method": "POST",  
                    "headers": {  
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"  
                    },  
                    "uri": "http://xxx/wcf/myrestservice.svc/is_online"  
                }  
            }  
        },  
        "actions": {  
            "office365connector": {  
                "type": "ApiApp",  
                "inputs": {  
                    "apiVersion": "2015-01-14",  
                    "host": {  
                        "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/resourcegroup1/providers/Microsoft.AppService/apiapps/office365connector",  
                        "gateway": "https://xxx.azurewebsites.net"  
                    },  
                    "operation": "SendMail",  
                    "parameters": {  
                        "message": {  
                            "To": "xxx@example.com",  
                            "Subject": "My Service Status",  
                            "Importance": "High",  
                            "Body": "Hi  @{triggers().outputs.body.Is_OnlineResult}"  
                        }  
                    },  
                    "authentication": {  
                        "type": "Raw",  
                        "scheme": "Zumo",  
                        "parameter": "@parameters('/subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/resourcegroup1/providers/Microsoft.AppService/apiapps/office365connector/token')"  
                    }  
                },  
                "conditions": []  
            }  
        },  
        "outputs": {}  
    }
```

I am wondering, how could I get the response of the HTTP call?
Then I want to send the same in the mail body.

Please correct me if I am going in wrong direction. Any response from you will be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manish!

Have you tried using "Content"?

```
@triggers().outputs.body.Content
```

Comment: Actually you are right but it will still not allow you to run the application there. It will automatically get executed on its defined  interval.

Comment: Have you tried using httpListener as the trigger?

[Pastebin sample](http://pastebin.com/YDu5Yz9z)